# Can't read Angular frontend origin url from ASP.NET Core API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, angular7, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to get requester URL from angular front end for some custom validation but can't read it on asp.net core web API  post method.

Comment: Show us some code